# javascript string pattern match gave null result

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

```
var listing = "<a name=\"id43ba766a68\" class=\"id\"></a>";
var hexid = listing.match(/name=\"id([a-f0-9]+)\"/);
```

I am getting hexid to be `null`. What is wrong here?

I tested it using the regex tester http://www.regextester.com/, it just returns as expected.

Comment: It works well for me - returns: `["name="id43ba766a68"", "43ba766a68"]`

Comment: Working perfectly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var listing = "<a name=\"id43ba766a68\" class=\"id\"></a>";
var hexid = listing.match(/name=\"id([a-f0-9]+)\"/);
```

is working correctly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nM8Vv/